# Django Quiz App, Measure Time Per View Render

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-apps

I am using the quiz app which you can see here:

https://github.com/tomwalker/django_quiz

Basically I want to measure the time it takes to answer a question in the quiz. Now how would I do that ?
Would this be possible to do in Django ?

Comment: Do you mean the time it takes for a person to answer a question they have open, or the time it takes for the backend to process the request?

Comment: I meant the time it takes a person to answer a question, sorry for being unclear. @waterproof